# trying to use johnsnow pretrained pipeline on spark dataframe but unable to read delta file in the same session

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, delta-lake, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

i am using the below code to read the spark dataframe from hdfs:

```
from delta import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



builder= SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark=configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()


#change file path here

delta_df = spark.read.format("delta").load('hdfs://localhost:9000/final_project/data/2022-03-30/')


delta_df.show(10, truncate=False)
```

and below code to use the pretrained pipeline:

```
from sparknlp.pretrained import PipelineModel
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sparknlp

# spark session one way
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark NLP")\
    .master("local[4]")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory","16G")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M")\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp-spark32_2.12:3.4.2").getOrCreate()


# alternate way #uncomment below to use
#spark=sparknlp.start(spark32=True)


# unzip the file and change path here
pipeline = PipelineModel.load("/home/sidd0613/final_project/classifierdl_bertwiki_finance_sentiment_pipeline_en_3.3.0_2.4_1636617651675")


print("-------")

# creating a spark data frame from the sentence
df=spark.createDataFrame([["As interest rates have increased, housing rents have also increased."]]).toDF('text')

# passing dataframe to the pipeline to derive sentiment
result = pipeline.transform(df)

#printing the result
print(result)

print("DONE!!!")
```

i wish to merge these two codes but the two spark sessions are not merging or not working for both tasks together. please help!

i tried merging the .config() options of both spark sessions and it did not work
also i tried to create two spark sessions but it did not work

a normal spark session is enough to read other format files but to read a delta file i had to strictly use this option : configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder)

is there any way to bypass this? or to make the code running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configure_spark_with_delta_pip` is just a shortcut to setup correct parameters of the SparkSession... If you look into [its source code](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/python/delta/pip_utils.py#L21) you'll see following code, you'll see that everything it's doing is configuring the `spark.jars.packages`. But because you're using it separately for SparkNLP, you're overwriting Delta's value.

Update 14.04.2022: it wasn't released at time of answer, but available in version 1.2.0

To handle such situations, `configure_spark_with_delta_pip` has an additional parameter `extra_packages` to specify additional packages to be configured.  So in your case the code should look as following:

```py
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", 
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.driver.memory","16G")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M")

my_packages = ["com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp-spark32_2.12:3.4.2"]

spark=configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder, extra_packages=my_packages) \
  .getOrCreate()
```

Before that implementation with extra parameters is released, you need to avoid using that function, and simply configure all parameters yourself, like this:

```py
scala_version = "2.12"
delta_version = "1.1.0"
all_packages = ["com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp-spark32_2.12:3.4.2", 
   f"io.delta:delta-core_{scala_version}:{delta_version}"]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", 
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.driver.memory","16G")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(all_packages)) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: i tried running this same code via spark-submit and it shows `configure_spark_with_delta_pip got an unexpected argument extra_packages ` this solution worked fine in PyCharm. Please help!

Comment: ah, it was not released yet...

Comment: guess ill have to wait then! thanks s lot for your help :)

Comment: No, don’t need to wait - see 2nd part of the answer

Comment: Version 1.2.0 was just released, and original answer should work